# Programmable Encoder, variable numbers of pulse/revolution!

Tags: control, encoder

Programmable Encoder, variable numbers of pulse/revolution!

Hey everyone. I'm doing my final course work and I have a problem with an encoder. Well schematically I have to feedback a frequency converter, that is controlling an induction motor, with this particular encoder. The issue is, I need to use the encoder, I'm forced, because is the only one that university have, but this encoder is incompatible with the frequency converter (FC). The encoder have a range of 50~10000 pulses/revolution, and the maximum number of pulses that the FC accepts is 4096 pulses/revolution. I already did some tests, and there is no way of the FC works with the encoder in this configuration. The encoder is programmable, I could use a cable, that i don't have,  to program it. This cable seems to be pretty simple, it look like a simple usb device (of course there is a software made by the manufacturer).

Finally my question, someone already used that encoder/cable, and know how it works?

I'll try to program the encoder without the cable.!

[The encoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT25O.jpg)

Comment: Consider dividing the pulses (not entirely sure if direction will be correct, but I think it should work just fine). Dividing by two is simple. So 50.000 => 25.000 => 12.500 => 6.250 => 3.125. Get yourself a 4-bit binary counter, one for each channel. For example there are two in single a 74xx393: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT393.pdf

Comment: Well I already thought to do this, but my concern is the time response (the frequency converter is used on vector control mode).  I'm going to do some tests and I'll let you know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking through the [technical information for the DFs60 encoder range](http://docs-europe.origin.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0e5e/0900766b80e5e070.pdf) it appears that the programming cable will be an essential part of gaining access to the encoder for the user programmability of the output lines/revolution count.

[image]

In looking at the normal pinning for the encoder connector it can be seen that the normal encoder signals of +A, -A, +B, -B, +Z, -Z, GND, SUPPLY, and SHIELD are documented.

[image]

The special order programming cable is clearly using the signal pinning of the encoder in a special way to adapt to a serial port connectivity via the D-SUB 9 pin connector off the adapter. The nature of the special usage of the signal lines for performing this programming is not documented on the encoder data sheets and so it if generally not feasible to try to work around this on your own.

**Your best bet at success with this is to contact the manufacturer (SICK STEGMANN) in Germany and explain your issues to them. Indicate that you are working in an educational institution setting and it may turn out that they may support you in one of two ways. One option is that they may donate a programming cable to your educational facility. The other option, which is much more likely, is that they may refer you to a dealer, distributor or sales/support office in your area where you could take the encoder and get it programmed into the format useful to your application.**

Comment: You are completely right. There is no information about how the cable works. Do you think that there is a specific circuit inside that cable, or it's a simple cable?

Comment: @RogérioPaludo - I wouldn't want to even venture a guess. It is likely that the "cable" uses a standard serial protocol. This comes from it being described as being equipped with a SUB D-9 in the documentation. If that is indeed the case then it is likely that the module in the middle of the "cable" may have some level converters to convert some of the signal wires from their normal voltage levels to the +/- levels used by a serial connection. ---- My guess is that that cable with a DB-9 connector may have been designed some years ago. These days it would be a USB Serial converter chip.